# Mod_rewrite и два вопросительных знака в URL

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте, уважаемые!
Необходимо редиректить запросы вида

```
Osite.ru/anything.php?sub=anything
```

на

```
so.kr/index.php?url=http://site.ru/anything.php?sub=anything
```

(для дальнейшей работы с полученным url).

Главная проблема в необходимом URL - возможное присутствие двух вопросительных знаков. Mod_rewrite, естественно обрабатывает только первый. Например, так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)osite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://%1site.ru$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Видя, что в URL уже присутствует знак "?", mod_rewrite подменяет второй вопросительный знак на "&".
То есть, URL

```
Osite.ru/anything.php?sub=anything
```

редиректится на

```
so.kr/index.php?url=http://site.ru/anything.php&sub=anything
```

а надо, как я уже говорил, на:

```
so.kr/index.php?url=http://site.ru/anything.php?sub=anything
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли решить задачу средствами mod_rewrite?

Заранее благодарю за любые подсказки!

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сделать вот так (т.е. вместо флага QSA явно добавляем к результирующему адресу строку запроса):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)osite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://%1site.ru$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

P.S. Да, этот, второй вопрос, кодируется в **%3f**, но это [правильно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL).

**UPD** Для эстетики:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)osite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://%1site.ru$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)osite\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://%1site.ru$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но я забыл упомянуть, что переменные в URL могут быть разные, а могут и не быть совсем. А в вашем случае даже если просто происходит обращение по osite.ru, он отредиректит его на http://so.kr/index.php?url=http://site.ru/? 
Оно, может, и пофигу, конечно, но не эстетично. Да и костыль. Хз к каким глюкам может привести.

Comment: Эстетику добавил, а глюков не должно ни каких быть с окончанием на вопрос.